# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'webservice_again.CustomUser' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

Complete Error:

> "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'webservice_again.CustomUser' that has not been installed

model.py

```
from builtins import ValueError
from datetime import date

import django
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
 from django.db import models

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

  def create_user(self, email, password= None, full_name="ABC",type = 0):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError("Email Required.")
    if not password:
        raise ValueError("Password Required.")

    user_obj =self.model(
        self.normalize_email(email)
    )
    user_obj.set_password(password)
    user_obj.full_name = full_name
    user_obj.type = type
    user_obj.save(using = self._db)
    return user_obj



 class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
   email =models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
   full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
   dob = models.DateField(default=date.today)
   type = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

   objects = CustomUserManager()

   def get_full_name(self):
     return self.full_name

   def __str__(self):
    return self.full_name
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'webservice_again',
'web_service',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "webservice_again.CustomUser"
```

Guys, I know this question is duplicate, but after going through all the provided solutions, i am asking this solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an app called `webservice_again`?

Comment: @10101010 - Yes. My App is webservice_again in the model.py of which i am making a CustomUser Model.

Comment: Is the module holding your `CustomUser` actually called `model.py` or is it really called `models.py`?

Comment: @WillKeeling - Does the error message which i mentioned really related to the question which you asked?

Comment: @RahulG Very likely

Comment: @10101010 - Do you have any solution friend? Currently, I am working on the same, but reaching no where.

Comment: Repeating the comment above are you sure the name of the file is `model.py` and not `models.py`?

Comment: @10101010 - Yes I am. I am using model.py. I just checked it.

Comment: As far as I know Django looks for models in a file called `models.py`. What I mean to say is you might want to try renaming `model.py` to `models.py`.

Comment: Rename the file to models.py or, create a new file models.py and import the CustomUser model inside it.

Comment: @10101010 and Ganesh Negi answer worked for me

Answer (score 0):

By default django looks for models in `models.py`. Try changing model.py file to `models.py`. If you somehow have a models folder which houses all your model files, then import the `CustomUser` model in `__init__.py` file located within the `models` folder. This should solve it!